# How can I replace Windows with Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, system-installation

I have a laptop with currently Windows 11 as the OS and I want to make a CA server out of the laptop because I don't need the laptop anymore. So, I want to install Ubuntu Server 22.04 on it. Now here comes the question: Will it replace/overwrite Windows 11 completely?
I already googled and saw [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-can-i-replace-windows-with-ubuntu), but that only covers the switch from Windows to Ubuntu (not Ubuntu Server). I'm not aware that it asks you if you want to replace the current OS with Ubuntu Server or does it? I'm just aware that it warns you during the Ubuntu Server installation that everything get deleted from the hard drive. Will that do the job of replacing/overwriting Windows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just installed 22.04 LTS on a pc with Windoze 10 on it from a bootable USB and one of the options in the setup was whether to replace the OS entirely which I did. No trace of Windoze now exists which is what I wanted to achieve 

Comment: @24601 Okay, thanks for your answer! I just wasn't sure if Ubuntu Server will also ask that and replaces it.

Comment: You can always delete Windows manually by removing all partitions and make the drive completely clear, then install a new OS onto it. You don't have to rely on the installer to do the job (although it does it pretty well :))

Comment: And unless you're really comfortable managing your system with command line only - Ubuntu Server edition does NOT include a desktop environment - then install regular Ubuntu Desktop and then whatever server tools you need (most likely you'd have to install them as well in the server edition). I'm saying this because a person asking questions such as this one don't strike me as proficient in Linux servers admin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace Windows with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/331353/how-can-i-replace-windows-with-ubuntu) the same methodology will apply with the server version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" replace the default boot screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552076/does-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu-replace-the-default-boot-screen)