# How do I completely remove focal fossa, so I can start fresh with jammin jellyfish

Tags: system-installation

I started my Ubuntu life with Bionic Beaver and was very happy at first but the more updates I downloaded the worse it got. I made the decision to upgrade to Focal Fossa and things got worse: every time I update I lose a driver and have to figure out what to download to fix it.

This time I want to start from scratch and not update. How do I completely delete focal fossa (and my problems) to make it so I can download Jammy Jellyfish from scratch?

Comment: Just install it, format all the partitions.

Comment: the easiest thing to do is to do a complete reinstall. So you would prepare a boot stick or a CD, boot from it and install the system from scratch. The default is that your hard disk/SSD will be repartitioned and your former system is gone. Is this what you were asking for or do you have special requirements like saving your home partition or s.th. else?

Comment: How are installing the original drivers?  Updates should not break drivers from the Ubuntu repositories.  Updates from some random source may not include all the "glue" code to copy/recompile drivers into new kernel module locations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" replace the default boot screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552076/does-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu-replace-the-default-boot-screen)

Answer (score 0):

A fresh install would definitely do it if you choose to overwrite your entire drive. Yon may want to keep a copy of the old drive though as an image if anything goes wrong. 'Disks' may be able to help you there.

Comment: Not a good answer. A good answer would to simply upgrade the OS with the tools offered and let that do it for you. Of course back up your data first not the whole OS.